# Error Loading Microsoft.Data.SqlClient Version=3.0.0.0

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

In VB.Net when I try to create a data Source I keep getting for following error "Could not load file or Assembly 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, Version=3.0.0.0').

I have used NuGet and installed the latest Verion (5.0.0.0) and it appears to be reference, but I still get the same error. I am at a loss. I can't find a reference to version 3.0.0.0 anyplace.

Comment: What version of .net or .net framework are you targeting?

Comment: The .Net framework is 4.7.2

Comment: Maybe right click the project in your solution explorer, in the references folder, remove all references to Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, then re-add it via Nugets

Comment: Tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: Here is the complete error message:
Some updating comments could not be generated automatically.  The database returned the following error:
Could not load file or assembly ‘Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, Version =3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=23ec7fc2d6eaa4a5 of one of its dependencies.  The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Is there specific functionality that you want from Microsoft.Data.SqlClient that is not provided by System.Data.SqlClient? I would generally tend to use the latter, which is referenced by default, in a NetFx 4.7.2 project.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are trying to get at, sorry.  I was trying to create data bindings for a couple of DataGrids in VB so I was trying to create a couple of Data Sources.  Didn't work.  However, the data does appear in Server Explorer.  I haven't worked in VB since about 2000 so I am rusty on the all the new ways of doing things.

Comment: I have tried to create a new project with nothing in it but form1 and the Access DB.  Same results.  I am at a loss.

Answer (score 0):

Try manually delete the bin and obj folders in the project folder, as well as the NuGet cache folder (usually in .nuget/packages in your user directory), then reopen the solution and build the project.

Make sure you don't have any binding redirects related to older versions of Microsoft.Data.SqlClient in your application's configuration files `app.config`

Comment: I have tried this and it didn't work.

Comment: Have you considered using System.Data.SqlClient as an alternative to your current Microsoft.Data.SqlClient?